# Checar se string existe - Procyon

Tags: java

Bom, estou tentando fazer um programa que lê o código de um arquivo .class, decompile ele, e verifique se existe uma string lá. Estou usando a library [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon), mas não sei como.

Esse é o meu código pra decompilar o arquivo:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        try {
            com.strobel.decompiler.Decompiler.decompile(
                "C:\\codigo.class",
                new com.strobel.decompiler.PlainTextOutput(writer)
            );
        }
        finally {
            writer.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você tem que fazer isso programaticamente? Não pode ser por linha de comando?

Comment: Sim, vai ser tipo um scanner de codigo